# What happens when you don't embed a font in flash?

Tags: flash, fonts, flash-cs5, embedded-fonts

I'm making some flash banners for a client, and our designer has used two custom fonts. The SWF needs to be 40k or less, so bandwidth is important.

The text is classic and static. I didn't really put much thought into how the SWFs compress fonts, but I guess if the user does not have the custom font installed, it will replace it with something they do. Of course, I need the font to display.

In some cases, depending on how many characters there are, I've kept the file size down and had the font look correct by using PNG images of the font or by using "Break apart" in Flash (both which increase the file size compared to just a font). Embedding the font, from my experience, increases the file size the most compared to my two workaround methods.

Are there any other methods available? I don't have much of an idea of what happens when you don't embed a font in flash, so my question really is... what happens?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Well I've had mixed results. When the designers review the creative, they see it just fine (probably because they have the fonts installed) whereas some of the project managers or even the clients don't see the correct fonts (and not all of them know enough about to design to know whether or not it is using the correct font).

I'm wondering if it really does have something to do with the local machine's installed fonts or if there's some secret data hidden somewhere or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't embed a font it won't display when someone doesn't have it installed - but you don't need to embed a font when you only use static textfields. Flash will embedd the glyphs which you used into swf.

Set 'generate size report' in publish settings to see exactly how much the fonts you've used weigh and try different methods (breaking apart, bitmaps for small text to see what you can get). Also, fonts differ in size, so sometimes if it's possible you can find a lighter one to use. One other hack is to save text (especially small size) as gif with solid background. Then use Flash bitmap quality settings to get the lowest weight while keeping the text legible, but of course it works best for small font sizes, like small disclaimers, etc.

Comment: I had also assumed that font did not need to be embedded when they were static textfields, but that didn't seem to be the case the other day when one of the project managers pointed out that the font didn't show up. Since the font was physically small, breaking it apart into vector shapes didn't increase the filesize by too much. In other cases though, I'll probably flatten them as a GIF first. I was using PNGs previously, but GIFs may save me more space.

Thank you.

Comment: It's easy to switch a text field accidentally to 'dynamic' or 'input'. I do it from time to time. As to txt->gif you can usually export it from Ps with very few colors (like 8) which reduces size as well.

Comment: Yeah. Most of the time, the font is usually one color (like white or blue). It's just the quality of the transparent edges that I'll get feedback on from time to time.

Comment: The gif method is best for static (non-animated) text. If the background is in uniform color you can save the gif with non transparent background. In general when you start working on a banner it's good to check the size of swf with nothing but all the text you need and adjust the design so it takes only the rest of the KB limit. Usually there's plenty other places for optimization like not tweening graphic objects containing multiple other objects, etc.